# Get Access to Blizzard Dev API with Spring oauth2 Authentication

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I would like to get access to the Blizzard Dev API. Unfortunately I can't get ahead with the oauth2 authentication.

I think I already tried every possible configuration combination, but without success. I am trying to implement an client credentials flow which is described here: https://develop.battle.net/documentation/guides/using-oauth/client-credentials-flow

My current code for the Configuration

```java
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Client
public class OAuth2Configuration {

    @Bean
    public OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails oauth2ProtectedResourceDetails(){

        AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails details = new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();
        details.setClientId("clientid");
        details.setAccessTokenUri("https://us.battle.net/oauth/token");
        details.setClientSecret("clientsecret");
        details.setGrantType("client_credentials");
        return details;
    }


    @Bean
    public OAuth2RestTemplate oauth2RestTemplate(OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext,
                                                 OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails details) {

        return new OAuth2RestTemplate(details, oauth2ClientContext);
    }
}
```

The Test Client:

```java
@Service
public class WoWItemClient {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public Item getItems(){
        String uri = "https://eu.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/item/19019";
   
        String result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);
        System.out.println(result);
        return null;
    }

}
```

with these settings I get the following error:

> Unable to obtain a new access token for resource 'null'. The provider manager is not configured to support it.

Can someone show me a working example?

Comment: What are you getting for errors?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer on my own. thanks to everyone who took the trouble.

all in all there were two problems:

1. with the uris, instead of https://eu.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/item/19019 it should be https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/item/19019?namespace=static-us&locale=de_DE 
   also the token request uri should start with us: https://us.battle.net/oauth/token
2. Instead of using AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails class i used ClientCredentialsResourceDetails. This error was obviously :D